# SpagoBI 5.0 socket error/can't use reports

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, spagobi

Error - Can't create socket + java/lang/noclassdeffounderror Java/lang/object

Hi, new to Spago, I know RDBMS but not file-based DBs

Problem seems something to do with Foodmart HSQLDB

I have installed 5.1 on win64 2008 server. Tomcat running fine and am able to add working postgres and MySql data connections. Datasets for both work fine and display data.

Running JRE and JDK 8.0_101 - JRE_HOME set to latter. Had problems installing originally as CATALINA and JRE_HOME environmental variables set in Windows were not read by scripts. Eventually got running after setting them directly in cmd window prior to running spagoBIstartup.

SpagoBI db seems fine, foodmart db throws errors (Cannot create poolableconnectionfactory (Socket Creation Error)

Dataset previews work with postgresql and MySQL But falls over trying to open any report or generate ad hoc SQL statements. Errors usually Impossible to load dataset [dataset] due to the following service errors:
socket creation error;

Open one of the inbuilt models and you can generate script. Fields displayed but running preview generates 
An error occurred in EXEC_QUERY_ACTION service while executing query: [SELECT t_0.BRAND_NAME, t_0.BRAND_NAME FROM Product t_0]

I think that the foodmart DB is failing to start and this is whats causing the errors. There are no log entries at all in the foodmart.log. If I try to start using start.bat I get a java runtime error java/lang/noclassdeffounderror Java/lang/object.

I've tried using the  java -cp hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.util.DatabaseManagerSwing command but get the same error.

Is this a compilation problem? It sounds like the class is present but there is no definition.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.When I replaced localhost with ip address. Now I figure out what was the reason for error.
In server.xml file you have to change the line of url of foodmart resource to **url="jdbc:hsqldb:file:${catalina.base}/database/foodmart"**

Comment: Thanks, Nilesh. That was the solution. It worked perfectly.